# Vulnerabilities in Scala

Tags: scala, security

I want to create a server side project using Scala.
I tried to search on the web for known vulnerabilities in Scala but I couldn't find any vulnerabilities that are not shared with Java, I know about the OWASP top 10 vulnerabilities, but I want to know if there is something specific for Scala.
Can you help?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi you might be better asking this sort of question on http://security.stackexchange.com/ which is more targeted towards security related questions.